# Optimizing Django-Tastypie-Postgres-Gunicorn to prevent Heroku request timeouts (H12) errors

Tags: django, rest, heroku, tastypie, heroku-postgres

I have a Django app running on Heroku for almost a year. I occasionally see request timeouts because a request took more than 30 seconds. The request is a fairly straightforward API call to Tastypie

API request is a `HTTP GET` on `/api/v1/x/?format=json&y=2&order_by=date_z&date_z__gte=2013-10-19T00:00:00&user__id=y`

The above is a request on a standard django model with some filters. There is one foreign key reference. Any way one can optimize these things?

I believe database indexes are one thing that could speedup things, but is that really the bottleneck?

I'm pretty sure the requests latency is accentuated by Heroku's routing mesh as well. Are there any best practices for this?

Comment: How many dynos do you have running? Heroku routes request to dynos *randomly* not intelligently, so even if you make your request as fast as possible, it's entirely possible that your requests still won't make it efficiently to a dyno that isn't busy.

Comment: @Brandon - From what I understand of the Request Timeout (H12) error codes on Heroku, scaling the number of dynos has nothing to do with individual requests timing out (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). I see other simultaneous requests being served one. What I face are occasional timeouts on some APIs which otherwise work fine.

Comment: Ah. It was my understanding that if all of your dynos are busy that requests will be queued, and because requests are routed randomly, the request might not go to a dyno that is initially free, causing requests to infinitely pool and eventually time out.